# How to obtain invariant tensors of a representation of a Lie algebra which contains nilpotent part?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Motivated by a field theoretical physics problem discussed in JPhysA50(2017)115401, I am looking for info on the representation theory of a Lie algebra of the form
$$E := N \rtimes (G \times L)$$
where $\rtimes$ denotes semi-direct product, $G$ is a compact Lie algebra ($\mathrm{u}(1)$ in the particular example), and $L$ is the $\mathrm{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ Lie algebra, while $N$ is a 20 dimensional real nilpotent Lie algebra which is 2-step and has four dimensional center and is regular in the sense that $[N,N]=\{\mathrm{center}\}$. Moreover, the Lie algebra $N$ is "singular" in the sense that there exist $x\in N\setminus\{\mathrm{center}\}$ such that $\mathrm{ad}_{x}:N\rightarrow\{\mathrm{center}\}$ is not surjective. The pertinent Lie algebra is constructed as the collection of algebra derivations of a particular complex unital associative algebra, being isomorphic (not naturally) to $\Lambda(\bar{S})\otimes\Lambda(S)$, the symbol $S$ denoting some two dimensional complex vector space, $\bar{S}$ denoting its complex conjugate vector space, and $\Lambda()$ denoting exterior algebra formation.

The concrete questions are:

1. Are there $\mathrm{ad}$-invariant bilinear forms on $E$ ?
2. Given some finite dimensional linear representation $E\rightarrow\mathrm{gl}(V)$, how can one find the invariant tensors in the tensor algebra of $V$?
3. What kind of generalities one can know on the representation theory of  $E$ ?
4. I managed to construct a faithful unitary representation of the Lie group of $E$ over a separable Hilbert space. How can one generate all of these faithful unitary separable representations?

Thanks,
Andras

Comment: 1. For non-degenerate ad-invariant bilinear forms on $E$ see [here](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00673991/document), Chapter $2$.

Comment: Dear Dietrich Burde, Thank you for your response. I briefly scanned the linked thesis, and found interesting info in it about several types of nilpotent Lie algebras. My question to your answer would be: did you mean to suggest me to apply a specific theorem from the cited document onto my problem, or did you primarily sent it as a kind of summary of the contemporary knowledge on the problematics? In case you meant a particular theorem, could you please point me there? Thank you! Andras

Comment: First question to you is: for 1., do you need *non-degenerate*? Otherwise we can take the zero form. For non-degenerate we deal with *quadratic Lie algebras*, so everything from the thesis applies.

Comment: Well, I am interested in the "least possible degenerate" one. I was able to construct a degenerate one via the homomorphism of $E\rightarrow G\times L$, where on $G\times L$ there is a non-degenerate one (on $G$ the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ scalar product, on $L$ the Killing form).